Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/styled
I've installed Material UI over Next JS latest and 14.2.16 version but still not working. I searched for compatible versions on documentation and also through Google but I can't find such information.
I'm calling a simple Button from @mui/joy and I'm getting the error "Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/styled'", but the module is installed. Please check attached files for detailed information. I appreciate any help.


